# Javascript file sizes, does this make a difference?

Tags: javascript, bandwidth, filesize

new to web design here and I have simple question.

I am creating a rotating header for a website and I have a couple of options.  I can use a script that I created that's only 2kb.  But the animation from frame to frame is a simple show/hide effect (very boring).  Or, I can use one of a couple of plugins that has the exact effect I am looking for, but the file sizes are either 20kb, 25kb or 32kb.

There will be a total of 5 images that I will be rotating with a file size of 40-60kb and the page it's on is going to have a lot of stuff.

I know it's best to keep file sizes as low as possible, making the 2kb script better to use but I was wondering if the difference of 18-33kb is that big a deal?

Any advice would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Try it both ways, and measure the performance.

I suspect an extra 30 KB won't make any noticeable difference to anyone not on dial-up, but keep in mind that these things add up over time.

Comment: wow very quick answer. I really appreciate it. I was actually in the middle of editing my post (few spelling corrections and reworded) and hit save and poof, I had an answer.

Answer (score 1):

It depends. How much traffic / hits does your site have? If its a small site with about 1.000 - 10.000 users it does not matter as they will cache the script after their first visit.

If you are concerned for speed on dial-up 30 KB is not much. You should go for the looks.